# Display Multiple Video in Window Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am beginner for the openCV.

I am using below codes to get four video in a file system and show to user. Like this:

```
V1 | V2
V3 | V4
```

Video length does not match, If the video comes to end I restart again:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2



v1 = cv2.VideoCapture('first.avi')
v2 = cv2.VideoCapture('second.avi')
v3 = cv2.VideoCapture('third.avi')
v4 = cv2.VideoCapture('fourth.avi')

v1_length = int(v1.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
v2_length = int(v2.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
v3_length = int(v3.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
v4_length = int(v4.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

count1=0
count2 =0
count3= 0
count4 = 0

while True:
    ret1, frame1 = v1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = v2.read()
    ret3, frame3 = v3.read()
    ret4, frame4 = v4.read()
    # print(ret1,ret2,ret3,ret4)

    if count1 == v1_length:
        a = v1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

        print(1,count1)
        count1 = 0
    if count2 == v2_length:
        b = v2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

        print(2,count2)
        count2 = 0
    if count3 == v3_length:
        c = v3.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

        print(3,count3)
        count3 = 0
    if count4 == v4_length:
        d = v4.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)

        print(4,count4)
        count4 = 0

    if ret1 and ret2 and ret3 and ret4:
        s1 = np.hstack((frame1,frame2))
        s2 = np.hstack((frame3,frame4))

        s3 = np.vstack((s1,s2))

        cv2.imshow("Result",s3)
        count1 += 1
        count2 += 1
        count3 += 1
        count4 += 1
    else:
        v1 = cv2.VideoCapture('first.avi')
        v2 = cv2.VideoCapture('second.avi')
        v3 = cv2.VideoCapture('third.avi')
        v4 = cv2.VideoCapture('fourth.avi')


    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
v1.release()
v2.release()
v3.release()
v4.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It works but I don't think it's a very good code. How can I write better?
How can I increase the number of videos more optimized? For example, how can I simply do it when it is 3x3 grid instead of 2x2 video?

Answer (score 3):

The main and the most noticeable problem is code duplication. Imagine you have not 4 but 64 windows.
That's 64 lines every time you need to do something for each video.

Put everything related to particular video instances in a list. When you need to do something for every video, write a for loop.

Instead of

```
v1 = cv2.VideoCapture('first.avi')
v2 = cv2.VideoCapture('second.avi')
v3 = cv2.VideoCapture('third.avi')
v4 = cv2.VideoCapture('fourth.avi')
```

you get

```
for idx in range(len(videos)):
    videos[idx] = cv2.VideoCapture(num2words(idx + 1, to='ordinal') + '.avi')
```

*In this case it's important that you iterate through the indices and change list values at those indices as opposed to iterating through the elements of the list `for video in videos:` and changing them (it won't actually affect the list).*

Then you can group videos by raws based on their index in the list.

After doing that your code will become thin and clean.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Is this true method or with pyqt5 ?

Comment: @hobik what's a true method?